# How do I remove an IronPython event from a C# event handler from WITHIN the event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ironpython

As an extension of this question:
[How do I create a C# event handler that can be handled in IronPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079265/how-do-i-create-a-c-sharp-event-handler-that-can-be-handled-in-ironpython)

My IronPython script looks like this:

```
def BarHandler(*args):
    Foo.Bar -= BarHandler

Foo.Bar += BarHandler
```

There are no errors, but BarHandler will ALWAYS be called and will never unregister itself. Now, if the code looks like this:

```
def BarHandler(*args):
    Foo.Bar -= BarHandler

Foo.Bar += BarHandler
Foo.Bar -= BarHandler
```

BarHandler will never be called. This leads me to believe that the BarHandler referred to within BarHandler is a separate instance which isn't getting removed from a list it doesn't belong to. However, something like `Foo.Bar -= self` results in `UnboundNameException: global name 'self' is not defined`. I assume it's because the C# event is not passing `self` as an argument but I haven't been able to get anything like that to compile. Closest I've come is:

```
    if (changed_selection != null) { //sending message to all delegates
        changed_selection(changed_selection, this, e);  
    }
```

Which I know is incorrect but I haven't been able to figure out.

It's probably useful to know I'm using IronPython with Unity so I'm on Mono 2.6 which is essentially a bastard version of C# 2.0.